# Write output of a while loop to multiple text files

Tags: python, printing, while-loop, text-files

I have two issues: the while loop is finishing at 1.1 not 1 and how can I save a text file for each value of alpha_min as the way I wrote the code, only the last message of alpha_min is being saved in the text file?

```
alpha_min = 0
alpha_max = 1

while (alpha_min < alpha_max):
    alpha_min += 0.1
    #Length of message 
    length_msg = (alpha_min * n)
    len_msg = int(length_msg)
    print(alpha_min)

    #Generates random messages, 1D vectora consisting of 1s and 0s for different values of alpha
    msg = np.random.randint(2, size= len_msg)
    print(msg)

    #Save messages in text format representing each bit as 0 or 1 on a separate line
    msg_text_file = open("msg_file.txt", "w")  # Path of Data File
    msg_text_file.write("\n".join(map(lambda x: str(x), msg)))
    msg_text_file.close()
```

Comment: To fix your first problem, change the < on line 4 to <=

Comment: @Qwerty didn't get you sorry

Comment: why not? what dont you get

Comment: @Qwerty I tried it still didnt work, im using python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only open the file once and close it at the end, because what you're doing right now is overwriting the file at each iteration (or you could use append rather than write)

```
alpha_min = 0
alpha_max = 1



while (alpha_min < alpha_max):
    alpha_min += 0.1
    #Length of message 
    length_msg = (alpha_min * n)
    len_msg = int(length_msg)
    print(alpha_min)

    #Generates random messages, 1D vectora consisting of 1s and 0s for different values of alpha
    msg = np.random.randint(2, size= len_msg)
    print(msg)

    #Save messages in text format representing each bit as 0 or 1 on a separate line
    msg_text_file = open("msg_file_{}.txt".format(alpha_min), "w")  # Path of Data File
    msg_text_file.write("\n".join(map(lambda x: str(x), msg)))
    msg_text_file.close()
```

Comment: still generated a single text file for some odd reason

Comment: What it's doing is generating a single file and putting all the contents in it. If you want one file per iteration, you have to have a different name for it (and move back the `open` and the `close` to your loop). For example, `f = open("message_{}.txt".format(alpha_min), 'w')` and then do what you want.

Comment: do i do this before the while loop or inside the loop?

Comment: thank you so much man! Is it possible to save multiple images resulting  from a for loop? as only the last image is being saved simialrly to the =text file scenario

Comment: I don't really understand the question... what do you mean by "multiple images" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144287/discussion-between-charles-b-and-thomas-kowalski).